# Rename categorical levels to reduce the number of levels

Tags: r

I have a categorical column which has around 1200 levels in a data-set of around 78000 records. I want to reduce the levels on the basis of occurrences. For eg. -:

- all levels occurring more than 2000 times be renamed to 'A'.
- all levels occurring more than 1000 times but less than 2000 times be
  renamed to 'B'
- all levels occurring more than 900 times but less than 1000 times be
  renamed to 'C'

And so on.

I don't want to group less frequently occurring levels into 'Others' as it would hide a lot of important levels.
Following is the dataframe for example.

```
df=data.frame(
  ID = c(1:10),
  Name = c("Jack", "Mike","Jack", "Mike","Jack", "Mike", "Tom", "Tom", "Smith", "Tony")
)
```

Here I would like to reduce the levels of column 'Name' by-:

- Renaming all levels occurring >=3 times as 'A'
- Renaming all levels occurring >=2 but <3 times as 'B'
- Renaming all levels occurring <2 times as 'C'

Can anyone help me to do it in R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `add_count` to count instances of `Name` and then check conditions with `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  add_count(Name) %>%
  mutate(NewName = case_when(n >= 3 ~'A', 
                             n >= 2 & n < 3 ~'B', 
                             TRUE ~'C')) %>%
  select(-n, -Name)

#     ID NewName
#   <int> <chr>  
# 1     1 A      
# 2     2 A      
# 3     3 A      
# 4     4 A      
# 5     5 A      
# 6     6 A      
# 7     7 B      
# 8     8 B      
# 9     9 C      
#10    10 C
```

Answer (score 2):

A base R solution using `table`

```
NameCount = table(df$Name)[df$Name]
NewName = rep("C", length(NameCount))
NewName[NameCount >= 2] = "B"
NewName[NameCount >= 3] = "A"
NewName
 [1] "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "B" "B" "C" "C"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `fcase` from the devel version of `data.table` (`1.12.9`), which would also do evaluation lazily

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, NewName := fcase(.N >=3, 'A',
                             .N >=2 & .N < 3, 'B',
                             default = 'C'), Name][]
#    ID  Name NewName
# 1:  1  Jack       A
# 2:  2  Mike       A
# 3:  3  Jack       A
# 4:  4  Mike       A
# 5:  5  Jack       A
# 6:  6  Mike       A
# 7:  7   Tom       B
# 8:  8   Tom       B
# 9:  9 Smith       C
#10: 10  Tony       C
```

---

Or using `base R` with `findInterval`

```
with(df, rev(LETTERS[1:3])[findInterval(table(Name)[Name], 2:3) + 1])
#[1] "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "B" "B" "C" "C"
```